# Cypress Testing - Expect input to be empty

Tags: cypress

I have an text input field that i would like cypress to check if it's empty.

I've tried:

```js
    cy.get('[data-cy=inputField]').should('not.have.value');

    cy.get('[data-cy=inputField]').should('be.empty');
```

both tests pass even though even though there is text in the field.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've found the solution. It works when i expect it to have the value of an empty string.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=inputField]').should('have.value', '');
```

Comment: nice. does that work when it is initially null or if someone tabs into and sets it to empty string. NICE!! I upvoted

Comment: Thank you. For me it works initially before the user has had any interaction with the field. I use it on a form in an Angular application where the field is initialized with the value null.

Comment: Hey there @DavidStorm Is there a way to check if there is 'any' data at all?

Comment: @LovelyAndy you could use something like `cy.get('input').invoke('val').should('not.be.empty');`

Answer (score 9):

You can also do it with the `:empty` pseudo-selector.

See Gleb Bahmutov's tutorial [Empty And Non-empty Elements On The Page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwMFsmWM4fM)

> We can find all empty elements on the page or its parts using `:empty` CSS selector.
> Empty elements have no children elements and no text inside.
> We can also find all non-empty elements by combining `:not(:empty)` selectors.

For your example code:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=inputField]:empty')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reset the form, then you can call:

```
cy.get(´your-selector´).should('be.empty');
```

Comment: How would that reset a form?